# Column Name Insert Error in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to insert column names into my R code with the code below, and keep receiving this error when I run the actual code:
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Would anyone know how to resolve this? I have already checked out the other articles on stack overflow on how to resolve this, but no one has posted WHERE in the code to enter the solution, so as a result I am not able to fix my code properly. NOTE: I left out the directory information, so please just focus on the actual content of the code. Thanks!

```
  for (fle in i.want.these.files){

#read in file to parse
mydata <- read.table(paste(my.in.dir,fle,sep = '/'), sep="|", allowEscapes = 
TRUE, fill = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "")


mydata[,1] <- gsub(" ", "", mydata[,1])
empty_rows <- which(nchar(mydata[,1]) == 0)
non_empty_rows <- which(nchar(mydata[,1]) != 0)

mydata2 <- NULL
for (i in 2:length(non_empty_rows)) {

var <- mydata[non_empty_rows[i],12]

for (n in (non_empty_rows[i]+1):(min(non_empty_rows[i+1]-1, 
max(non_empty_rows), na.rm =T))) {

  var <- paste0(var, mydata[n, 12])

}

mydata2 <- rbind(mydata2,
                 cbind(mydata[non_empty_rows[i], 1:11], var))

colnames(mydata2) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L")


}

write.table(mydata2, file=paste(my.out.dir,"rolled_message_test1.csv", 
sep="/"), sep=",",  col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

}
```

Comment: WHERE in the code do you get an error? If you set `fle <- your_first_file` and step through line by line, which line creates the error?

Comment: I just resolved this issue myself. the write.table function should look like this:write.table(mydata2, file=paste(my.out.dir,"rolled_message_test1.csv", 
sep="/"), sep=",",  col.names = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L", row.names = FALSE)

Comment: You certainly don't need to do `colnames(mydata2) <- ...` inside your loop - you could do it just once right before `write.table`. And you also could just use the default `col.names = T` inside `write.table()` instead of re-specifying the column names that are already there.